# Unable to get an array of objects from firebase using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> I am developing a cart application, and my products are stored in
>   firebase database. On fetching the data I am getting each product
>   separately as an array.  I am using Context API here. Below is the
>   code.

```
class ProductProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    products: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setProducts();
  }

  setProducts() {
    let products = [];
    let product = firebaseConfig.database().ref("dataJson");
    product.on("child_added", snap => {
      products = snap.val()   
      this.setState(
        () => {
          return { products };
        }
         , () => console.log(this.state)
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is not working properly, and how you would want it to work?

Comment: I want my products to be array of objects.

Comment: And what is happening currently? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: {products:{...}}  {products:{...}}  {products:{...}}  {products:{...}}  {products:{...}} I am getting like this on console.log(this.state

Comment: each  {products:{...}} has one product

Answer (score 0):

Try to push your value for each entry in your database to your products array like that:

```
setProducts() {
  let product = firebaseConfig.database().ref("dataJson");

  product.on("child_added", snap => {
    let products = [];
    products.push(snap.val());
    this.setState({ products });
  });
}
```

Comment: on console.log(this.state.products) , I get 8 array of objects with each have all 8 products

Comment: What exactly is one snap.val() containing? (Don't work with firebase.) It looks like snap.val() already contains all objects. In this case, try to put let products = []; before the this.setState argument. (See updated code.)